# Importing and Exporting variables in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Is there any way i can import and this **routes variable** in another file. Note I **don't** want to **import router** just **routes** variable.
Code below is what i tried to do

**src/router.js**

```
const routes = [
{
    path:"/",
    name:"home",
    component: HomeTemplate
},
{
    path:"/heroes",
    name:"heroes",
    component: /*webpackChunkName: Heroes*/ import("@/components/DcHeroes/DcHeroes")
},
{
    path:"/calendar",
    name:"calendar",
    component: /*webpackChunkName: Calendar*/ import("@/components/CalendarTemplate")
},
{
    path:"/markdown",
    name:"markdown",
    component: /*webpackChunkName: Markdown*/ import("@/components/MarkDownTemplate")
},
]
const router = createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    base:'/'
})
export default router;
```

**src/components/navbar/index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Navbar</h2>
        <router-link :to="{ name:'home', }">Home</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name:'heroes', }">Heroes</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name:'calendar', }">Calendar</router-link>
        <router-link :to="{ name:'markdown', }">MarkDown</router-link>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
        import routes from '@/Router.js'
        export default{
            name: "NavbarTemplate",
            mounted(){
                console.log(routes);
            }
        }
</script>

//import {routes} from '@/Router.js'
// This returns a large object
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you want to import routes? Are you using vue-router?

Comment: Yeah  I want to loop through this routes and create a dynamic navbar.

Comment: Have you tried `export const routes`?

Comment: When you are exporting you are using `router` instead of `routes`

Comment: Yeah I added export before routes as well and the answer by @Boussadjra_Brahim is somewhat solving my problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `export const routes` like

```
export const routes = [
{
    path:"/",
    name:"home",
    component: HomeTemplate
},
...
]
```

then import it like :

```
 import { routes } from '@/Router.js'
```

or you could get access to that routes using `this.$router.getRoutes()` method:

```
<script>
    
        export default{
            name: "NavbarTemplate",
            mounted(){
                console.log(this.$router.getRoutes());
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why adding {} gave me the array?

Comment: you're welcome this is a an ES6 syntax that allows you to export many modules from one file there's only one module/variable that could be exported by default and imported without using `{}` but you export multiple modules using only `export` and you should import them using `import {module1,module2,...} from '/someFile.js'` for example you could do `import router,{router} from `@/Router``

Comment: to learn  more check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

Comment: @ChiragArora `import stuff from './some-file'` => imports the ***default*** export of the file and assigns it to `stuff` in the current scope. `import { stuff } from './some-file'` looks for any export named `stuff` in the exports of the file and assigns it to `stuff` in current scope. That's the difference.